# Going from two switches (fan and light) to single pole dimmer switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

I removed a ceiling fan that had two switches, one for the fan and the other for the light.  There is 14/2 coming in to the box for power and 14/3 running to where the fan was.  The lights work fine with the two separate switches but when I wire the new dimmer I either can’t turn off the lights or I get no power at all.  I’m capping off the red wire, have two neutrals together and black incoming into outlet along with black going to lights.  Any ideas why I can’t get the switch to properly power the lights?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: It would have been Really Helpful to have a photo of the box before you had removed the old switches, too.  That would have told you/us whether the outgoing red was the fan and outgoing black was the light, or vice versa... or if someone had been "creative".

Comment: Note that this is a general tip: When redoing anything, it is ALWAYS a good idea to take notes, and photos since they're now free, of what it was before you started changing it. Good insurance that if all else you can put it back to the way it was, and good reference material if you need to ask for help.

Comment: " I’m capping off the red wire, have two neutrals together and black _incoming into outlet_ along with black going to lights." What outlet? Are you referring to where the light mounts to the ceiling? Is there actually a receptacle involved somewhere? Is this "outlet" the switch? Please [edit] to clarify.